# Which exceptions other than FileNotFoundException can Files.size(Path) throw?

Tags: java, linux, file, size

I have a RedHat 7 machine and want to get size of a regular file residing on Ext4.

The [Files.size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#size(java.nio.file.Path)) declares an IOException. Which other exceptions might be thrown, other than [FileNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)?

Using Java 7 and nio package.

Comment: Why do you care? The documentation states: `IOException` or `SecurityException`, so you can only rely on that. The rest is an implementation detail.

Comment: I know how to handle FileNotFoundException (skipping the file), and want to understand if other exceptions should be skipped or infinitely retried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method *cannot* throw FileNotFoundException.

It can throw a [`FileSystemException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystemException.html), one of:

- NoSuchFileException,
- AccessDeniedException,
- others.

It can also throw an `IOException` which means an I/O level error (disk problem, maybe) and not a filesystem level error.

In short, the best way to deal with either is:

```
try {
    Files.size(...);
} catch (FileSystemException e) {
    // deal with fs level error
} catch (IOException e) {
    // deal with I/O level error
}
```

Comment: How can you know that it can't throw a FNFE? The javadoc doesn't say anything about it...

Comment: @assylias none of the JSR 203 methods can throw that exception; in JSR 203 this exception is superseded by `FileSystemException` and children, including `NoSuchFileException` and others.